# Regex with xml finding content between tags

Tags: xml, regex

I'm looking for a regex to help me parse xml content.

I found this one while searching - `(?<=Message\>)[\S\s]*?(?=\<\/Message)`

And it works almost perfectly. It finds (lazy, not greedy) everything between `<Message>` and `</Message>` !

But my problem is that Message tag could also have an attribute and when it does this regex does not work.

How can I fix this regex so if there is an attribute it will still match for it?

I tried startswith `Message(.*)?>` but it didn't work

Thanks !.

Comment: This one is about (X)HTML, but I think it applies to XML as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1163867

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

It Will Give you Content Between Tags and It's Attributes.

```
<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>
```

[REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/Z8F1EMOku9)

It Will Give you Content Between Tags only.

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

[REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/Bl4MRBCEz1)